# Matching and Combining Multiple 2D lists in Python

Tags: python

I am trying to combine (2) 2D lists based on a common value in both lists.

The values in the list are unique so there is nothing to take in to account for a list entry having any of the same values.

The example is:

```
list1 = [['hdisk37', '00f7e0b88577106a']]
list2 = [['1', '00f7e0b8cee02cd6'], ['2', '00f7e0b88577106a']]
```

With the desired result of:

```
list3 = [['hdisk37', '00f7e0b88577106a','2']]
```

The common value is at list1[0][1] and list2[1][1].

Comment: So the final output must only contain the merge of lists which have an element in common?

Comment: how should look the result for this input: `list1 = [['a','b'], ['d', 'f'], ['a', 'e']]
list2 = [['c','d'],['e','b']` ?

Comment: Sorry, I should have clarified.  I will always be trying to match the second element of the lists.  So always `listm[k][1]` and `listn[p][1]`.  Also the matching values will always be unique.  I'll give my actual example to make it more clear.

`[['hdisk37', '00f7e0b88577106a']]
[['1', '00f7e0b8cee02cd6'], ['2', '00f7e0b88577106a']]`

Desired result:

`[['hdisk37', '00f7e0b88577106a','2']]`

All the fields will be unique in their lists.

Comment: @user3552459, please, edit your question pasting the new example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The *pythonic way* to get the needed result using `set` objects:

```
list1 = [['hdisk37', '00f7e0b88577106a']]
list2 = [['1', '00f7e0b8cee02cd6'], ['2', '00f7e0b88577106a']]

set1 = set(list1[0])
list3 = [list(set1 | s) for s in map(set, list2) if set1 & s]
print(list3)
```

The output:

```
[['00f7e0b88577106a', '2', 'hdisk37']]
```

- `set1 & s` is *intersection* of two sets(returns a new set with elements common to the first set and all others)
- `set1 | s` is *union* of a specified sets

Comment: That worked.  Thanks Roman.  I'll study this information for the future.  Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
result = []
for inner_list1 in list1:
    for inner_list2 in list2:
        set1 = set(inner_list1)
        set2 = set(inner_list1)
        if set1.intersection(set2):
            result.append(list(set1.union(set2)))
```

For each inner list in both lists, check if the intersection between them is not empty. In case it isn't, they are both merged and added to the final result.

Answer (score 0):

This method returns all the possible "second value" matches as a dict, from the second value to the resulting list.  It also takes an arbitrary number of these lists of lists (not just two).

```
import collections

a = [['hdisk37', '00f7e0b88577106a']]
b = [['1', '00f7e0b8cee02cd6'], ['2', '00f7e0b88577106a']]

def combine(*lols): # list of lists
  ret = collections.defaultdict(set)
  for lol in lols:
    for l in lol:
      ret[l[1]].add(l[1])
      ret[l[1]].add(l[0])
  return {k:list(v) for k,v in ret.items()}

print combine(a,b)
```

Output:

```
$ python test.py 
{'00f7e0b8cee02cd6': ['00f7e0b8cee02cd6', '1'], '00f7e0b88577106a': ['hdisk37', '2', '00f7e0b88577106a']}
```

To get your exact output requested, you'd do:

```
combine(list1, list2).get('00f7e0b88577106a')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wanna try something different you could do a

```
merger = lambda x,y : set(x)|set(y) if set(x)&set(y) else x
results = []
for item in list1:
    result = reduce(merger,[item]+list2)
    if isinstance(result,set):
        results.append(result)

print results
```